# Can't seem to subtract dates in Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, date, datetime

Code is below, I am simply trying to subtract 2 dates, and figure out if the date difference meets a certain threshold. Can't seem to figure out how to get them in the right format for this.

```
def activity_breakup():
    now = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print("now is equal to {}".format(now))
    for activity in convert_csv_to_list()[1:]:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(activity[2], '%m/%d/%Y')
        print("date is equal to {}".format(date))
        if now - date == 0:
            activities_in_next_7_days.append(activity)
        elif now - date <= 7:
            activities_today.append(activity)
        else:
            continue
```

Output of the prints are:

```
now is equal to 2018-04-17 00:00:00
date is equal to 2018-04-22 00:00:00
```

Comment: `now` is a `str` and `date` is a `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strftime` returns a string object (think: string **from** time).

`strptime` returns a date object (think: string **parse** time).

Looking at your code, `now` is a string and `date` is a date object.  The error indicates this as well.

If you want to compare dates, change the type of `now`.

```
def activity_breakup():
    now = datetime.date.today()
    print("now is equal to {}".format(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

    for activity in convert_csv_to_list()[1:]:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(activity[2], '%m/%d/%Y')
        print("date is equal to {}".format(date))
        if now - date == 0:
            activities_in_next_7_days.append(activity)
        elif now - date <= 7:
            activities_today.append(activity)
        else:
            continue
```

On an unrelated note, perhaps `now - date` is supposed to return the number of days?  Currently it's returning a `datetime.timedelta` object.  You can do the following:

```
        days_diff = (now - date).days
        if days_diff == 0:
            activities_in_next_7_days.append(activity)
        elif days_diff <= 7:
            activities_today.append(activity)
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a datetime object instead of a string in your first statement:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.today()
```

The last portion of your corresponding line is just to convert it to a string with a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

`stftime` returns a string while `strptime` returns a `datetime` object. Just move the `strftime` into string formatting.

```
def activity_breakup():
    # now is a datetime now
    now = datetime.date.today()

    print("now is equal to {}".format(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

    for activity in convert_csv_to_list()[1:]:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(activity[2], '%m/%d/%Y')
        print("date is equal to {}".format(date))
        if now - date == 0:
            activities_in_next_7_days.append(activity)
        elif now - date <= 7:
            activities_today.append(activity)
        else:
            continue
```